# How to print & to Excel from VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have been trying to code &, as in the character & chr(38), but it keeps underlying the word. any solution for this?

```
Private Sub createMenu()
'define the variables
    Dim mnuDownload1 As Menu

    'create the menue bar
    With MenuBars(xlWorksheet)
        .Reset
        .Menus.Add "Import", 1

        'define the menue bar
        Set mnuDownload1 = MenuBars(xlWorksheet).Menus("Import")

        'for each defined menu bar at the sub item , the first "" is the name of the item. The second "" is the macro name
        With mnuDownload1.MenuItems
         .AddMenu Caption:="P&S"
         .Item("P&S").MenuItems.Add "Exclude P" & Chr(38) & "S", "changes"
        End With
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Is this all the code? As you have written it or with chr(38) will show "&" in the msgbox

Comment: Your code works just fine for me. It displays the & just as you want.

Comment: Sorry I updated above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed normal behaviour, one time `Chr(38)` underlies the next character when busy in the `menuitems`. A `msgbox` will display a normal ampersand. If you want to use the ampersand as a character in a menuitem, use it twice as in `"Exclude P" & Chr(38) & Chr(38)  & "S"`, or `"Exclude P&&S"`.